# How do I set Lightning as the default calendar app?

Tags: thunderbird, calendar, lightning

I want to set Thunderbird's calendar extension, Lightning, as the default calendar app. Is this possible?

Comment: @ Johannski: well perfectly right, this command installs the add-on quite nice but I'm afraid it is not the answer to the question if one can set up lightning/thunderbird as the default calendar application (within the system info).. and as far as I looked it up on other posts, it is not possible at the moment -
for further information please follow the link below to the latest thread: askubuntu.com/questions/101261/is-it-possible-to-set-lightning-as-the-default-calendar-application

Answer (score 10):

Thunderbird can be set as default calendar application by opening the file:

`$HOME/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`*

In a text-editor such as *GEdit* and adding the line `text/calendar=thunderbird.desktop` to the [Default Applications] section. You may or may not need to add that same line to the [Added Associations] section too.

*To find and open this file, press the button combo <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> in your home folder, and look for `.local`, then find the file, right-click it and Open with..., or just double-click. After adding the line, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>, answer YES when asked to save.

See also this [comment in the bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+3.0/+bug/841409/comments/21).

Comment: Following this answer makes Thunderbird the default calendar application. By the way, opening a calendar files makes Thunderbird to create a new mail message with the calendar attached.

Answer (score 4):

Edit the MIMETYPE line in /usr/share/applications/thuderbird.desktop to read:

```
MimeType=message/rfc822;x-scheme-handler/mailto;text/calendar;text/x-vcard;
```

Then run `sudo update-desktop-database -q`

Now in "Default Applications" you will find Thunderbird in the list of calendar applications.

Source: http://onemoretech.wordpress.com/2014/02/12/thunderbird-as-default-gnome-calendar/

Comment: This worked perfectly under Ubuntu 16.10 to add Thunderbird to "Details > Default Applications". Thank you. :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Calendar Extension for Thunderbird**

Install this plug-in by clicking this link: [xul-ext-lightning](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xul-ext-lightning) [image: Install xul-ext-lightning]

or open a terminal (e.g. gnome-terminal) and type:

```
sudo apt-get install xul-ext-lightning
```

That's all, folks!

Comment: thanks, but how can i install it? i tried through software center, but it doesnt work. What do i need to do? thanx

Comment: just click on the icon

Comment: what icon? lightning extension is installed, but i cannot set it up as the default calendar for ubuntu...

Comment: Thanks works perfectly well for me!
actually the right command is sudo apt-get install xul-ext-lightning @Panagiotis: You have to open the terminal. Just open the Dashsite (the ubuntuicon in your sidebar) and search for terminal. Then copy my command and change to the terminal. There paste the code (right click-> paste). Then you only have to type in your password and press y for agreeing to install it. But you will get the instructions anyways. :)

Comment: I installed this and it said that it was already at the latest version however I don't have the option to set Thunderbird/Lightning as the default calendar app in Unity?

Comment: [Bug 841409](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+3.0/+bug/841409) may be to blame if you cannot set Lightning as the default calendar app in Ubuntu 11.10 or later.