# Lightning is not compatible with Thunderbird 7.0.1

Tags: 11.10, thunderbird, compatibility, lightning

I reinstalled Ubuntu 11.10 the other day and now when I try to install the Lightning extension in Thunderbird it states: Lightning is not compatible with Thunderbird 7.0.1.

As extra information lightning is not comming up automaticly when searching for it within Thunderbird. You need to download it manually.

And also I had it installed before I reformated the computer.

Anybody has a solution to this issue?

Comment: have you tried this ? -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/76921/how-do-i-set-lightning-as-the-default-calendar-app/77287#77287

Comment: **Ubuntu 11.10** now has **Thunderbird 8.x** available, from **ppa:mozillateam/thunderbird-stable**.  This does support **Lightning 1.0**, so can issue now be closed?

Comment: New Ubuntu 11.10 install has Thunderbird 9.0 and says Lightning is not compatible with this version.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest making sure you're using the version in the Ubuntu archive instead of the version from addons.mozilla.org.  The package is called [xul-ext-lightning](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xul-ext-lightning) (Click to install). We keep lightning updated with Thunderbird.

There will be an upgrade to 8 early next week that should come with a new compatible lightning as well.  Also, the version in the Ubuntu archive is architecture specific as opposed to addons.mozilla.org which is i386 (32 bit) only.

Comment: Can you add the link, you mention?

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problems short after a new Thunderbird version came out. The solution is, to wait with installing the newest version of thunderbird only, when all the extensions are also available in a compatible version.

Answer (score 1):

The latest Lightning 1.0 only works with Thunderbird 8.0. For Thunderbird 7, download Lightning 1.0b7 from here: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/lightning/versions/

That is the only version that works with Thunderbird 7 so make sure you don't download some other version. Once downloaded, in Thunderbird open "Addons", click the icon on the left of "Search all add-ons" and select "Install Add-on from file", browse for the downloaded Lightning 1.0b7 .xpi and you're done.

Comment: This method is not currently working.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the package as of today has no "-extension" in its name. This worked for me:

`sudo apt-get install xul-ext-lightning`