# How to enable TLS Client Certificate Authentication in Evolution?

Tags: ssl, certificates, webdav, tls

I access my contacts via WebDav on the work LAN in evolution. Recently these contacts are also available via https and client certificate.

I have added the certificate authority and client certificate as shown in the pic below:

[image]

The addressbook is added as Type WebDav/Use a secure connection.

However, I still get the following handshake failed errors:

```
Unable to open address book
This address book cannot be opened.  This either means that an incorrect URI was entered, or the server is unreachable.

Detailed error message: Unable to connect to 'xyz': Error performing TLS handshake: Decryption has failed.
```

(The same certificate and CA work perfectly in Firefox, also accessing the same addressbook and calendar with the same tls client certificate works perfectly on my Android device, the calendar leads to the same problem, the server runs egroupware)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it seems, this is not possible right now. As an alternative you can use Thunderbird + the [SoGo Connector](http://www.sogo.nu/downloads/frontends.html)

In this case install in Firefox the SoGo Connector. Then Install your CA authority and client certificates in Thunderbird via

EDIT --> Preferences --> Advanced --> Certificates

If you also like the Unity integration that Evolution calendar offers, you will need to:

1. set Thunderbird as a default calendar application by opening the file:

> $HOME/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list*

in a text-editor and adding the line:

> text/calendar=thunderbird.desktop

to the [Default Applications] section.

You may or may not need to add that same line to the [Added Associations] section too, as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76921/how-do-i-set-lightning-as-the-default-calendar-app#) (thanks user92046)

2. Install the evolution Mirror plugin

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:markjtully/ppa
>
> sudo apt-get install xul-ext-evolution-mirror

3. Don't uninstall evolution as it is still used in the background

This was all testet on Ububtu LTS 14.04.03 with the Unity Desktop. The CalDav CardDav server is [Egroupware](http://www.egroupware.org/start.html).