# Caldav (and carddav) compatible client with support for TLS Client certificate authentication

Tags: calendar, certificates, tls, caldav

I am in search of a Caldav (and carddav) compatible client with support for [TLS Client certificate authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Client-authenticated_TLS_handshake)?

The solution with Thunderbird + Lightning + [SoGO connector](https://sogo.nu/download.html#/frontends) I suggested in my answer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/680750/how-to-enable-tls-client-certificate-authentication-in-evolution) question does not seem to work any more.

On android I have used CalDAV-Sync and CalendarSync, both of which work fine.

PS: I am still highly interested in an answer to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the meantime, it seams that Thunderbird supports TLS Client certificates without the SoGo connector. I can not identify when this functionality was added. (It might also be relevant that we now use a third party CA Authority).

The certificates are inserted in preferences --> Advanced --> Certificates --> Manage Certificates as shown in the following two pics:

[image]

and here:
[image]

For CalDAV I additionally had to install the [Cardbook](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/cardbook/) add-on.